# Flexible .htaccess file for local and online environment

Tags: .htaccess

I got a simple Wordpress .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

What i am searching for is how to make the .htaccess be aware in which environment it runs, to change the RewriteBase and RewriteRule accordingly.

Something like (dummy)

```
if HTTP_HOST == "192.168.0.1" RewriteBase /localfolder, RewriteRule . /local/index.php [L]
else (for all other domains assume online) RewriteBase /, RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried something like

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =192.168.0.100
RewriteBase /local/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /local/index.php [L]
```

but don't get it to work. always the first rules are apllied

### UPD:

This seems the perfect solution for offline and online:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: The way Wordpress tackles this is by generating it using the programming language Wordpress is written in.

Comment: I don't understand your comment? I just need to rewrite my .htaccess for online/local. Wordpress initiale creates a .htaccess for the environment it is installed. I need different rules for different environments.

Comment: In the server config file you could possibly have used `VirtualHost`. For `RewriteRule`'s you could add a condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =192.168.0.1`. For `RewriteBase` I would have no idea.

Comment: I updated my question with your suggested `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =192.168.0.100` but it doesn't kick in. Did i misspell anything?

Comment: I tried a lot and ended up surprisingly easy: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress` this works for both, offline and online.

Comment: If that solves your problem, please post it as an answer and accept it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems the perfect solution for offline and online:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```